# Typescript error: Argument of type '() => () => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, socket.io

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly and how I should be type constraining to avoid having this error in my `useEffect`. One solution is to either cast my `newSocket` or type my `useEffect` return value as `any`, but I don't think that's ok.

My code:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import type { Socket } from "socket.io-client";
import io from "socket.io-client";

interface SocketProviderInterface {
  id: string;
  children: JSX.Element;
}

const SocketContext = React.createContext<Socket | null>(null);

export const useSocket = () => {
  return useContext(SocketContext);
};

export const SocketProvider = ({ id, children }: SocketProviderInterface) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io(`http://localhost:3333`, { query: { id } });
    setSocket(newSocket);

    return () => newSocket.close();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My error:

```
function(): () => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>
Argument of type '() => () => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type '() => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.
    Type '() => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to type 'Destructor'.
      Type 'Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to type 'void | { [UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY]: never; }'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Figured it out. The mistake was that I was doing cleanup like so `return () => newSocket.close();` and consequently returning a `Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>` type.

Solution was to make the `newsocket.close()` call inside of curly braces so that the return value remains void, like so:

```
return () => {
  newSocket.close();
};
```

Would appreciate any further elaboration if my interpretation is faulty here.